# Korea Visa-exemption for Australian Visa holders

Tags: visas, transit, south-korea, indonesian-citizens, australian-residents

I'm an Indonesian citizen (Indo passport), staying in Australia with a valid Australian visa (not PR, not citizenship). My travel plan is:

Australia -> Japan (2 weeks) -> Korea (2 weeks) -> Australia

OR

Australia -> Korea (2 weeks) -> Japan (2 weeks) -> Australia

Am I eligible for the Korea 30-days visa exemption here?

Answer (score 1):

Both cases work: the rules state that you need to be going either **from** OZ **to** Korea, and then a third country, or **from** a third country **to** Korea, onwards to OZ. There's another possibility involving a 4th country and short duration of stay, but I forgot exactly what it was.

In any case, your itineraries both work.